# Cronjob for jpegoptim and optipng

Tags: image, product-images, optimization

I want to create a cronjob that runs jpegoptim and optipng everyday, to optimize images in my Magento install.
I want to run this on my CentOS 7 install.

Therefore I edit /etc/crontab with the following:

```
0 13 * * * root lockrun -Q -L .lockjpegoptim -- find /media -iname *.jpg -exec jpegoptim --max=90 --strip-all --all-progressive -p {} \; > /dev/null
0 13 * * * root lockrun -Q -L .lockoptipng -- find /media -iname *.png -exec optipng -o7 -preserve {} \; > /dev/null
```

I want to be sure that this is correct, will this run right? 
Is there a way to check if the cron run succesfully?

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar requirements, and implemented this free extension on a site of mine instead: https://marketplace.magento.com/apptrian-apptrian-image-optimizer.html

I found it more convenient because it integrates with Magento cron, and you can set batch size etc. It also provides some visual on how far it is etc.

There were a few changes to the location of the binaries (optipng/jpegoptim), but after that it has worked great.